# In PHP Google calender API invalid client secret JSON file

Tags: php, json, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate google API. But i am getting error

Error in command prompt :

Uncaught exception 'google_exception' with message invalid client secret JSON file

[image]

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: _invalid client secret_ Seems to be all you need to know. Seems like its time to hit the books or even _heavens forbid_ the documentation

Comment: You will need to create oauth2 credentials and download the client secret file from google developer console.

Comment: I already have create oauth2 credentials and download the client secret file. it may be some configuration error.

Comment: Did you follow the PHP quickstart for Calendar API where JSON file is of type Other?